# Why isn't my future value available now?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, async-await, promise

My ajax call is not returning anything! Here is my code:

```
var answer;
$.getJSON('/foo.json') . done(function(response) { answer = response.data; });
console.log(answer);
```

Even though the network call is succeeding, and I can see that the response contains data, the console logs "undefined"! What is happening?