# Can't set class member variable from callback

Tags: javascript, redis, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set a class member variable from a callback of a function I'm calling from the class constructor.

To be a bit more specific: I need to set the connection ID in the Connection class constructor based on the Redis INCR result (each client has a 'global' connection ID so I can have multiple nodes).

Here's the code.

```
class Connection {
  constructor() {
    client.incr('conn_id', (err, reply) => {
      this.connID = reply;
    });
  }
}

var lovely = new Connection();
console.log(`lovely connID is ${ lovely.connID }`);
```

This is the result: `lovely connID is undefined`

Comment: Not familiar with Redis but is `client.incr` asynchronous? That could mean you are running the console.log line before the callback to client.incr has had a chance to run.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959257/why-isnt-my-future-value-available-now.

Comment: Your problem is not that you "can't set class member variable from callback", but that you "can't access class member variable before it's set".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that client.incr('conn_id' ....) is async , which means the callback will be invoked after  your code  run .

So

console.log(`lovely connID is ${ lovely.connID }`); will be called before the callback

> (err, reply) => {
>         self.connID = reply;
>       }

which is similar to this :

```
class Connection{
  constructor(){
    self=this;
    setTimeout( function(){self.client='somevalue';
                          console.log('value1');}, 10)

  }
}

var a = new Connection();

console.log(a.client);
```

running this will result

> undefined 
>        value1

Comment: Sure, so how should he fix it?

Comment: if he needs to log it , he should do that inside the callback , and if he needs to do more things he can call a function inside the callback

Comment: I wasn't asking for myself; I was suggesting that your answer was missing this part and should be amplified. Logging from inside the constructor isn't that great. What if I want to log from outside the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

As others here have mentioned, the issue seems to be that `client.incr` is asynchronous and your code does not wait for it to resolve before accessing the properties. To remedy this issue, you could try passing in an `onReady` callback to `Connection` to enssure the properties will be there before trying to access them. Something along these lines:

```js
'use strict';

// mock client.incr
var client = { incr: (id, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, 'Hello World'), 0) 
}};

class Connection {
  // receive an "onReady" function
  constructor(onReady) {
    client.incr('conn_id', (err, reply) => {
      this.connID = reply;
      // call "onReady" function, and pass it the class
      if (typeof onReady === 'function') onReady(this)
    });
  }
}

new Connection(lovely => { console.log(lovely.connID) })
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: We are still using callbacks in this age of Promises? What if he wants to access the `connId` outside the constructor; how will he know if it's ready or not?

Comment: @torazaburo I saw it as a straight forward way to demonstrate what was wrong and how the sequence of events happen -- not a final implementation (thus the phrase: "... Something along the lines of ..."). If OP wants to use promises after he/she understand the data flow, then so be it, and he/she can use your answer as a guide. Thank you for providing that alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In general putting heavy initialization logic in a constructor, especially if it's asynchronous, is not a good idea. As you've found, the constructor has no way to return the information about when the initialization is finished. An alternative is to create a promise for when the connection is ready. Then, in your outside code, you can hang a `then` off the property to specify the code you want to trun when it's ready.

```
class Connection {
  constructor() {
    this.connId = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      client.incr('conn_id', (err, reply) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(reply);
    });
  }
}

var lovely = new Connection();
lovely.connId . then(connId => console.log(`lovely connID is ${ connID }`);
```